# angular having multiple navbars

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular and now playing around with ui-router. I have setup

//app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
'ui.router',
'appControllers'
```

])

```
app.config(function($stateProvider){
 $stateProvider
     .state('courses',{
         url: '/courses',
         templateUrl:'partials/courses.html',
         controller: 'CourseListCtrl'
     })
```

})

//controllers.js

```
var appControllers = angular.module("appControllers", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router'])
appControllers.controller('CourseListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
$http.get('data/courses.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.courses = data
    console.log(data)

})
}])
```

//index.html

```
<body>
 <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

// courses.html

```
<div style="text-align: center" class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="c in courses>
<a href="#/overview/1"><img src="../img/team-placeholder.png" alt="Team photo"></a>

   <br>
   <span>{{c.title}}</span>
   <p>{{c.description}}</p>
```

When i run this on my localhost and go to /courses I get the following error:
Error response

Error code 404.

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.

I hope one of you guys know what i did wrong, because i cannot figure it out.

Thnx

Comment: What server is this running on?

Comment: Simple HTTP Server Python

Comment: You can possibly forward all requests to the index.html using this suggestion: http://serverfault.com/questions/124190/simple-http-server-that-will-send-the-same-file-for-all-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to `#/courses`.  If you make the `/courses` request directly, your server will try to serve that path unless you have a rewrite operation of some kind going on.  You should have the server rewrite all requests to the index.

If you don't want to use the `#/courses` syntax and use `/courses` directly *while the app is already running*, use `$locationProvider.html5mode(true)`